# Is there a js equivalent to php echo, including all merits?

Tags: javascript, php

I've been using php for altering html & css on my website. It is as straightforward as I could possible imagine. Just echo the variable wherever you would actually insert the *border-color* or the *title* value, and you're all set.
I want to be able to do just that on JS.

That is, I want to define js vars to equal the php variables, & then use the js vars IDENTICALLY to my php approach. Meaning, INSIDE the html/css expression, w/o altering it whatsoever. This way I'll be able to change the values presented on the go, given user actions.

I DON'T want to use js commands such as document.getElementId('whatever').style.color... I got hunderds of php variables, not just a few, and it'd be a nightmare. I also DON'T want to set css variable to equal the js variables which equal the php variables, or such rather demanding workarounds (again, hunderds of changes at hand, & I don't want to make it any worse). I want to use the very same approach I used with php (and it's fine if it just doesn't exist on js of course, but THAT is the question).

PS If there's a way to change the php variables on the go instead, that could work too. I just assumed it'd be easier to just set them as js vars, which are essentially SUPPOSED to change on the go.

Comment: Sounds like you've bad design solutions at hands causing a nightmare from the beginning. There's no native `echo` in browsers, but you can search for a client-side template engine suitable for your purposes.

Comment: It's unclear why you want to directly port something you're doing in php to js - are you, e.g., in the middle of porting an app from php to node.js or something? The 'why' you are trying to do this would be helpful. Please edit the question to address.

Comment: Agreed, this sounds like a really strange thing to want/need to do...it would be good to understand the motivation (and any constraints) in order to try and suggest something meaningful / realistic as an approach. When you say `on the go` do you mean "without refreshing the page"? Ultimately it sounds like you might be looking at a substantial change of architecture, rather than an easy conversion. Client-side and server-side code operate in fundamentally different ways, so there's unlikely to be a simple direct conversion to satisfy all scenarios, unless your PHP code is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Preface: Generating your entire page content using client-side JavaScript is not generally best practice.

---

The closest **direct** equivalent built into the browser environment is [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write), and you're probably not going to want to use it for several reasons:

1. It's really verbose because you have to wrap everything in `<script>...</script>`.
2. The HTML spec — which defines it — [argues against its use](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dynamic-markup-insertion.html#document.write())
3. It doesn't work everywhere.

   - You can't use it in the body of a `<title>...</title>`. (You can work around that by assigning to `document.title` instead.)
   - You can't use it *inside* a tag (between the `<` and `>`). This doesn't work, for example:

     ```html
     <!-- Doesn't work: -->
     <div class="<script>document.write('x')</script>">___</div>
     <!-- Doesn't work: -->
     <div <script>document.write("class=x")</script>>___</div>
     ```

Other than that , it works. Instead of:

```php
// PHP
<div><?=variableGoesHere?></div>
```

it would be

```html
<!-- JavaScript in HTML -->
<div><script>document.write(variableGoesHere)</script></div>
```

You could shorten it a bit by defining your own `echo` (and taking the opportunity to support multiple arguments):

```js
function echo(...msgs) {
    document.write(msgs.join(""));
}
```

Then it would be:

```html
<!-- JavaScript in HTML -->
<div><script>echo(variableGoesHere)</script></div>
```

---

Alternatively, you could write your page entirely in a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), then output it in a single assignment to `document.body.innerHTML` (or even `document.documentElement.innerHTML`, but if at all possibly I'd write the `head` of the document normally), like this:

```html
<!-- Here you'd have the usual

<html>
<head>
(head content)
</head>
<body>

...but Stack Snippets provide that -->
<script>
// Your variables
const x = "ecks";
const y = "why";
const z = "zee";

// Writing the HTML in a template literal:
document.write(`
    <div>The value of x is ${x}</div>
    <div>The value of y is ${y}</div>
    <div>The value of z is ${z}</div>
`);
</script>

<!-- </body></html> -->
```

Unlike script tags with `document.write` in them, you can do your substitutions anywhere.

With the right IDE add-ins, you'd probably even get HTML syntax highlighting within the template literal.

Alternatively, you could search for client-side rendering libraries, but those are the built-in options that immediately come to mind.

Comment: I understand why it might sound extremely ugly coding, but I'm already using the php variables in the way I described, and I'm looking for a minimum effort conversion from the php to js, which is probably the blech you mentioned. I'm not going to change my entire architecture, for now.
So let's focus on the blech for a sec. It doesn't actually work-- script inside title seems to not be valid html (it acutally just sets the string "<script>document...." and so on as the title...). Any way to still make it work? Thanks :)

Comment: I might need to clarify -- I tried it inside the <title> lol. Work with php, not with js. probably would be the same for every use of string in html obviously.

Comment: @DanielF - Yeah. That's interesting about `title` (and it rings a **faint** bell), and you can't do it *within* a tag (between the `<` and `>`), but there we are. Re the minimum effort conversion, I'm not at all sure the template literal isn't your simplest option. For each page, `<body>body content here</body>` becomes ```<body><script>document.write(`body content here`);</script></body>```. It's mostly inserting ```<script>document.write(` ``` at the beginning and ```​`);</script>``` at the end. :-)